# How can I call a function when page loads with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I want to trigger a JavaScript function after the page loads all the elements and I have to echo some HTTP request data into the page somewhere and use JavaScript to get the information from the DOM.

Therefore, I create the function and fire it on page load using jQuery but it didn't call the javascript (I think the DOM hasn't loaded) so how can I fix this?

```
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        myFunction(); // firing the function 
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    function myFunction(){
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    var formscount = target.textContent(); // the number of items from [#target]
    alert(target);
    if (formscount > 0) {
        active="";
        for (i=0; i < formscount; i++) {
            var str='active'
            if (i > 0){
            str =  ''
            }
            $('#DOM').append($('SOME HTML ELEMENTS');        
            event.preventDefault()
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

DOM Called (target) for passing the data (`$_POST['itemscount']`):

```
<?
$count = $_POST['itemscount'];
?>

<div id="target" style="display:none;">
<?  $output = $_POST['productscount']; // or $Count //
    echo htmlspecialchars($output); 
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, **textContent** is not a function.
So it should be written like this:

```
var formscount = target.textContent;
```

Second thing, you are missing the closing bracket **)** in line `$('#DOM').append($('SOME HTML ELEMENTS');`

```
$('#DOM').append($('SOME HTML ELEMENTS'));
```

Third thing, `event.preventDefault()` will not work, as event is undefined. You may remove it.

and lastly, php tags begins with `<?php` and not with only `<?`.

```
<?php
$count = $_POST['itemscount'];
?>

<div id="target" style="display:none;">
<?php
    $output = $_POST['productscount']; // or $Count //
    echo htmlspecialchars($output); 
?>
</div>
```